# Why my screen goes white on calling API for first time but it works on second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

As I mentioned in title my screen goes white on calling API for first time but when I refresh and inputs the value it works properly

on console the error is : Uncaught TypeError: Value.map is not a function

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [Value, setValue] = useState('');

  const APIurl = async () => {
    await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`).then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  };

  const APIurl1 = () => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}` + `/repos`)
      .then((response) => {
        setValue(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      });
  };

  const handleKey = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      APIurl();
      APIurl1();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="bbody">
      <input
        id="search-bar"
        onChange={(event) => setUser(event.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter User"
        type="text"
        onKeyPress={handleKey}
      />

      {!data.name ? (
        <div>
          <p className="errorMsg">No Data Found</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="inner-img">
          <img src={data.avatar_url} alt="" />
          <h2>{data.name}</h2>
          <p>{data.bio}</p>
          <div id="repos">
            {Value.map((value) => {
              return (
                <a key={value.id} href={value.html_url} target="_blank">
                  <button id="repos-link">{value.name}</button>
                </a>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

I m trying to get Github profile of a person by inputting name in the input field and extracting the info from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Because the initial state of `Value` is an empty string. Nothing is there, so there's nothing to map. When you use `setValue` after typing in the input its state is updated to reflect whatever you've typed, so only then can you map over `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there is `Value`, add `Value &&` like so:

```
 {Value &&
   Value?.map((value) => {
     return (
       <a key={value.id} href={value.html_url} target="_blank">
         <button id="repos-link">{value.name}</button>
        </a>
      );
  })}
```